# How do I escape a bad VPN sign on request

Tags: vpn

I get stuck and have to wait until the request times out when I enter a bad VPN request. I would like to cancel the request and enter a different VPN address. I tried control break like on Windows but it doesn't work.

I am using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client version 3.1.05170.
I use the company's default. Depending on how I am connected the VPN client doesn't recognise the .com address and I need to go to terminal mode and "ping" the site to get the IP address. Then cut and paste that to the VPN address bar.

Does anyone have better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could try with the native option in your mac to use a different way to connect to your VPN, try this:

Go to **System reference** > **Network** > add a new connection (the plus sign on the down left corner) on **interface** select "VPN" on **vpn type** select "Cisco VPN" change the name (if you like), Add your company's values and try it to connect, I used this option and my VPN works like a charm.